# Use Imported Data from a CSV to create Line Chart with D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a script to build a complete Line Chart. It works fine, but I would like to work more generally. Therefore I want to import and convert strings from a CSV without knowing the Headers of the columns.

I am able to convert the data into an array using this:

```
var data = d3.csv("data.csv")
        .row(function(d, i, columns)
             {
                for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) 
                    {  
                        d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]]
                    } 
                return d;


        })
        .get(function(d){console.log(d);});
```

But I am not able to use this data to build the chart.

Before I imported like this:

```
d3.csv("Messdaten.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d){
d.T = +d.Time_seconds;
d.Y1 = +d.Temp2_C;
d.Y2 = +d.Temp3_C;
});
```

This way I had variables for every column, which I could use to build Axes/Lines etc.

How can I access the seperate columns with my "new" method?

EDIT my Code for better understanding:

```
var margin = {top: 100,
          right: 200, 
          bottom: 100, 
          left: 200
         },
width =window.innerWidth-margin.left-margin.right,
height =window.innerHeight-margin.top-margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);


var yTemp = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
            .tickSizeInner(-height);

var yAxisTemp = d3.axisLeft(yTemp)
            .tickSizeInner(-width+margin.right-margin.left);


var line1 = d3.line()                           
    .x(function(d){return x(d.T);})     
    .y(function(d){return yTemp(d.Y1);});
var line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){return x(d.T);})     
    .y(function(d){return yTemp(d.Y2);});


var svg = d3.select(win1.document.body).append("svg")   
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var Diagramm1 = svg.append("g") 
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ","+ margin.top + ")");


svg.append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width) 
    .attr("height", height);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 32])               
.translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]) 
.extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);


d3.csv("Messdaten.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d){
d.T = +d.Time_seconds;
d.Y1 = +d.Temp2_C;
d.Y2 = +d.Temp3_C;
});


x.domain([0, 100+d3.max(data, function(d){return d.T})]);
yTemp.domain([0, 5+d3.max(data, function(d){return d.Y1})]);
Diagramm1.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .attr("d", line1);
Diagramm1.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", line2);
Diagramm1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxisTemp)
Diagramm1.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label1")
    .attr("x",-50)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text(yAxisName1);
    Diagramm1.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label2")
    .attr("x",-50)
    .attr("y", 40)
    .text(yAxisName2);
Diagramm1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x",width)
    .attr("y", 28)
    .text(xAxisName);

})
```

Comment: Have you looked at this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Your question is unclear.  In the end you need to know something about your data.  Is it safe to assume that the first column is your x data and that subsequent columns are y-values of separate series?

Comment: @Mark - Yes, first column x data, following y data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `d3.csv` **doesn't return anything**. Actually, it returns an object related to the request, which clearly has nothing to do with the data itself.

Therefore, this...

```
var data = d3.csv(etc...)
```

... will simply not work.

We can clearly show this. Have a look at the console in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w9C5ZzWfBkt1UYKzDY8O?p=preview), in which I'm using your code. This is the `data` you get:

```
{header: ƒ, mimeType: ƒ, responseType: ƒ, timeout: ƒ, user: ƒ, …}
```

Again, it's an object related to the request, not the CSV you loaded.

**Solution**: put the row function between the URL and the callback, and use the data array **inside the callback**:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]]
    }
    return d;
}, function(data) {
    //use data here
})
```

Comment: I understand that I have to use my data at the place you marked, but i still dont get how to access them afterwards. Like the value of Column one for my x-Axis. 
Maybe I will understand it with a direct example of my Code.
I want to build a line Chart. so I have this Part   
 `        var line1 =      d3.line()       
  .x(function(d){return x(d.T);})  
  .y(function(d){return yTemp(d.Y1);});    `

With my "old method" I could just use d.T for x and different d.Y for my Y-value. Could you explain what I have to change in this part? 


Thank you very much!!

Comment: This is **another** issue, and therefore you should post another question. Please, don't edit your post to ask about further problems. The issue here is very clear, and I solved it: `d3.csv` returns nothing. Mark this as solved and post **another** question regarding those problems with the line chart.